# Oracle CDC in Talend

Tags: talend, oracle-cdc

I am trying to setup a CDC in Talend on an Oracle database. I am following the steps as listed here: https://www.talendforge.org/tutorials/tutorial.php?language=english&idTuto=42

However, when i try to establish the CDC in the main DB conneciton, i get a message saying `"Database information must be filled to use the cdc!"` and the `Create Subscriber` button is disabled.

What could I be doing differently? I have created two connections pointing to the same database, and have also retrieved the table schema in my main connection.

Comment: At what point are you getting your error?

Comment: I was getting the error at the 'Create CDC' step under the data connection. However, i am not getting this error now, what i did was change the connection type of my CDC connection to Oracle SID connection (earlier , it was Oracle Custom). I see that this particular error occurs when the connection type of the CDC connection is Oracle Custom - it doesnt occur when the conn type is SID or Service based.